# How to format string using write function?

Tags: c, unix

In my C program, I am printing a string to the command terminal using `printf("%d %s %s\n", node->id, node->date, node->input);` but I need to now use the write function `write(STDOUT_FILENO, cmdline, strlen(cmdline));`...

How can I format the string like I did using printf?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`sprintf`/`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to format the string into a character buffer, and then `write` that.

Comment: Actually, don't get into the habit of using `sprintf()` - it will only lead to crashes and vulnerabilities later on!  Only ever use the versions of these functions with buffer overrun protection.